# Установка View программно

Tags: android, view, android-customview

Написал кастомный `View` для карты

```
public class MetroMapView extends ScrollView
{
Context ctx;
List<Station> list;
RelativeLayout v;
LayoutInflater inflater;
View station;
DisplayMetrics metrics;
HorizontalScrollView xScroller;
List<View> stations;

public MetroMapView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(ctx, attrs);
    this.ctx = ctx;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((GameActivity)ctx).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    v = new RelativeLayout(ctx);
    v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    v.setMinimumHeight(metrics.heightPixels * 2);
    v.setMinimumWidth(metrics.widthPixels * 3);
    xScroller = new HorizontalScrollView(ctx);
    xScroller.setScrollContainer(true);
    xScroller.addView(v);
    addView(xScroller);
    setScrollContainer(true);
    setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
}

void setElements(ArrayList<Station> list) throws Exception
{
    this.list = list;
    for(Station s : list)
    {
        View station = inflater.inflate(R.layout.station_view, v, true);
        station.setId(View.generateViewId());
        station.setX(s.getX());
        station.setY(s.getY());
        v.addView(station);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

В `ScrollView` сидит `HorizontalScrollView`, а в нем - `RelativeLayout`, в котором я размещаю `View`. В метод `setElements` я передаю коллекцию станций. Каждая станция имеет координаты x и y. Вот так я делаю в активности

```
List<Station> stations = new ArrayList<>();
Station lt = new Station(0,0);
Station rt = new Station(metrics.widthPixels * 3 - 50,0);
Station lb = new Station(0,metrics.heightPixels * 2 - 50);
Station rb = new Station(metrics.widthPixels * 3 - 50, metrics.heightPixels * 2 - 50);
stations.add(lt);
stations.add(rt);
stations.add(lb);
stations.add(rb);
try {
    map.setElements(stations);
}
catch (Exception e) {
Log.d("$", e.toString());
}
```

В итоге получаю такой лог

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Но я не пойму, что значит уже занят. Нахожу решения где нужно удалять `View`, но мне это не надо, они должны остаться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас в методе `setElements(ArrayList<Station> list)` в следующей строке:

```
View station = inflater.inflate(R.layout.station_view, v, true);
```

Передаётся `boolean` параметр `true`. Это значит, что вы просите присоединить создаваемую Вами `View station` к корневой `View v`, которую Вы также передаёте в качестве параметра.

А потом говорите:

```
v.addView(station);
```

и тут вылетает Ваш `IllegalStateException`.

А всё потому, что внутри метода `inflate` при передаче параметра `true` и без того неявно вызывается `v.addView(station)`, где `station` запоминает своего `parent`. В тексте ошибки так и говориться "Не хочу к этому дяде, у меня уже есть свой Папа!" (вольный перевод). При этом не важно, что этот дядя и есть тот самый Папа, такая проверка там отсутствует :)

Вам нужно либо убрать параметр `true`, либо убрать строку `v.addView(station);`, в зависимости от Вашей `xml`-разметки.

P.S.: Хватит уже повсюду таскать за собой `Context`, каждая `View` содержит его в себе, Вам достаточно лишь вызвать метод `getContext()` :)

Comment: контекст в кастомной view - обязательный параметр конструктора, без него не вызвать конструктор родителя и соответственно, в кастомной view вы не получите контекст методом getContext() если его не будет в родителе.

Comment: я не про конструктор, а про то, что он Context выносит в поле класса :)

Comment: если контекст передан в класс, логичнее и правильнее держать его в поле класса, чем постоянно дергать метод. Постоянная ссылка дешевле вызова метода

Comment: Если он дёргается по 100 раз в секунду, то да, а если только при инициализации, то это увеличивает количество строк кода, что ухудшает читаемость. А если конкретно, экономия на дёргании методов, которые редко вызываются - это экономия на спичках.

Comment: дело даже не в экономии на спичках, а в культуре кода, в андроид это устоявшаяся практика с контекстом и наоборот улучшает читаемость (особенно если код стандартных view вы читали и используете при создании своих) . getContext() - внешний метод, для "наружного применения", внутри view принято использовать поле класса.

Comment: View в себе содержит поле Context и еще множество полей, если каждый наследник по цепочке будет вытаскивать всё те же самые поля к себе, то размер каждого наследника будет неуклонно расти. А если следовать логике - не дёргай методы, выноси всё в поля, то и без того большие классы превратятся в огромные.

Comment: Думаю не стоит развивать эту тему тут, в данном случае Context в поле класса явно излишен, хотя бы просто потому что далее по коду он нигде не используется :)

Comment: это всего лишь ссылка, она занимает в памяти не больше места чем код вызова метода, а использование обходится дешевле. Вообще, вы можете поспорить с разработчиками android, зачем они в каждый наследник "тащат" поле класса, я с ними согласен и останусь при своем мнении

Comment: Вот тут Вы и попались :) Ни один наследник View из стандартных компонентов Android НЕ тащит за собой Context в поле класса! FrameLayout, RelativeLayout, TextView, ImageView... более того, они не гнушаются использовать внутри наследников метод getContext().. так что хватит спорить с разработчиками Android и соглашайтесь с ними :)

Comment: Спасибо, но я нашел решение. Гляньте мой ответ

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте проверять добавили ли вы уже вьюху. Т.е. вместо

```
v.addView(station);
```

Сделать:

```
if(station.getParent() != null){
    v.addView(station);
}
```

Comment: Безрезультатно. Может это из-за того что корневым является `ScrollView`, добавляю в `RelativeLayout`? Но он же его ребенок

Comment: @Flippy, ну хоть покажите где именно у вас падает...

Answer (score 1):

Разметка которою я инфлэйтил была без родителя, тоесть `View`. Обернул его в `LinearLayout` и все заработало.